# Reputation between different communities or groups on Stack Exchange - is it a combined reputation?

Tags: discussion

I notice whenever you sign up to a new group you have to register your Stack Exchange or Gmail account (whichever signup method you chose) with that particular community.

If I have for example 172 reputation does that mean across all the communities I am a part of (*Stack Overflow*, *[Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Tex - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/tour)*, etc.) that I have a combined 172 reputation?

Is it possible to see how much reputation you have from individual communities?

That is, how much of my 172 reputation is made up of questions/answers on Stack Overflow, vs *Photography*, vs *Bicycles*?

Comment: You have separate totals, its not combined. Get some points and you will see. As for registering to different groups, i guess there are different servers to serve the groups so you need to log in each time you go from one group to the other. Its like App within an App within an App etc. That's my guess

Answer (score 3):

Each community has its own reputation (except meta pages).

You can see your reputation for each community on your profile on the bottom left:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3098818/yoshiserry

[image]

Also, you can have a combined view if you navigate to "flair" in your profile.

Comment: The combined flair only includes accounts with 200 points or more. That means that the OP currently will get a ['sad face' combined flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/-1.png).

Comment: To make the answer more complete, you could mention the association bonus (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/).